# How to identify a binary model with varying mean and variance

Tags: regression, mean, logit, probit, binary-data

I have the following model,

Yi = 1.( Xiβ + εi > 0) where εi~ Ɲ(Ziδ,1).

or

Yi = 1.( Xiβ + εi > 0) where εi~ Ɲ(0, (µ + Ziδ)2)

with a binary model, can i identify β and δ in such a model? How? and what conditions enable me to identify this model?

Answer (score 1):

Your first model with $X_i \beta$ for the latent location parameter and $Z_i \delta$ for the mean of the errors is somewhat unusal. As both linear predictors pertain to the mean on the latent scale one would usually put all regressors into a single $X_i \beta$ which comprises all available regressors ($X_i$ and $Z_i$ in your notation) and use a zero-mean error term $\epsilon_i$ (as you do in the second model).

In the second model, the variance is over-specified in your notation. You can have an error term $\epsilon_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, (1 + Z_i \delta)^2)$ or alternatively $\mathcal{N}(0, \exp(0 + Z_i \delta))$, i.e., using a sqrt- or log-link on the variance with its own linear predictor. However, then $Z_i$ *must not* contain an intercept. One typically fixes the intercept in such a way that for $\delta = 0$ the variance is 1 as I have done in my notation above.

The reason for this is that the overall variance on the latent scale is not identified. You can just identify *variance differences* between the groups defined by the regressors $Z_i$. However, you may need a lot of observations over a sufficiently large range to estimate the parameter $\delta$ well. It may also be hard to distinguish variance differences in $Z_i$ from non-linearities or interactions in $X_i$, especially if the underlying variables overlap.